# Testing applications behind the firewall with Okta

Tags: okta

Getting started with Okta in a "security-conscious" organization, where connecting across the firewall requires a mound of paperwork.

Wondering if there are any best practices for testing applications internally before heading to the DMZ. There are two parts that we're primarily concerned with:

1. Authentication - any way we could emulate authenticating against something like an Okta preview env't without traversing the firewall?
2. API testing - while doing internal development, it would be great to be able to make API calls like "create user" against *something* that is purely internal - even if it's just a stub.

Answer (score 1):

Okta doesn't currently offer a full-fledged mock Okta client, so there's no officially supported method for testing Okta locally.

There's a partial, undocumented mock-okta client [here](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular-1/blob/master/tools/mock-okta/index.js). However, it currently only supports the `/oauth2/v1/authorize` authorization code flow.